# Resize UICollectionView bounds to fit the cells (using Storyboard + Auto Layout)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, uicollectionview

I dragged and dropped a **UICollectionView** from my storyboard onto an area of an existing UIView, see below:

[image]

I don't want to allow scrolling/paging in that **UICollectionView**, so I disabled those options from the inspector builder.

What I want to achieve, is making the **UICollectionView**'s frame/bounds to **auto resize** to fit all the cells. Which sounds pretty simple.

I was expecting the **sizeToFit** to handle it. But it didn't do anything..

I even tried to manually changing these to some hardcoded values, and nothing worked...:
**setFrame:**, **setBounds:**, **invalidateLayout**, etc... to no avail.

To make it simpler, I even removed all constraints I had on that **UICollectionView**, and I still can't change the size in code.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try calling a method(say updateMyCollectionViewFrame) in the method

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

when the last `item` is encountered.

Comment: I tried that, didn't work either. The only thing that kinda worked was to create an outlet to the "height" constraint, and change that in the code.. I don't like that approach. Seems hacky.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do with Swift :) You can use it in obj-c as well:

```
self.newsGrid.reloadData();
self.newsGrid.performBatchUpdates({ () -> Void in

}, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
    print("bounds ");
    println(self.newsGrid.bounds);
    print("size ");
    println(self.newsGrid.contentSize);
});
```

Call these methods when you are done setting your data source.
(Note: prints are just for demonstration, you can set height constraint there, or just alter the UICollectionView frame using the contentSize property).